# OpenLayers resolutions from web.config

Tags: javascript, asp.net, openlayers

I am trying to store my map's resolutions in web.config and the property in my ASP.NET is a string

**web.config**

```
<maplayers>
  <bufferMaps useBufferMaps="1" zoomOffset="13"     resolutions="19.1092570678711,9.55462853393555,4.77731426696777,2.38865713348389,1.19432856674    1945,0.5971642833709725"/>
</maplayers>
```

When I read the `resolutions` property in my javascript I get the following error:

> Object [19.1092570678711,9.55462853393555,4.777314…66741945,0.5971642833709725] has no method 'sort'

I think it may be because it's a string but how can I solve this?

**My javascript**

```
var str1 = "[";
var str2 = "]";
var res_str=str1.concat(ob.resolutions,str2);

var mapnik_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM(
      "OpenStreetMap", 
      "http://localhost/WebClient/Openstreetmap/${z}/${x}/${y}.png",
      {zoomOffset: 13,
      resolutions:  res_str}
      );
map.addLayers([mapnik_layer]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you suspected it's because `resolutions` is supposed to be an array rather than a string.

> **[OpenLayers.Layer.resolutions](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.resolutions)**
>   {Array} A list of map resolutions (map units per pixel) in descending order.

The [`string.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method, takes a string as input and splits it into an array at a given delimiter - in this case at each comma `,`:

```
var res_str = ob.resolutions.split(',');
```

The output of which is:

```
["19.1092570678711", "9.55462853393555", "4.77731426696777", "2.38865713348389", "1.194328566741945", "0.5971642833709725"]
```

An array of strings, rather than just a string:

```
"[19.1092570678711, 9.55462853393555, 4.77731426696777, 2.38865713348389, 1.194328566741945, 0.5971642833709725]"
```

Comment: Note that in your question one of the floats has a load a spaces in it (`1.19432856674____1945`), assume this is a copying and pasting error but if not you need to remove the spaces.